# Creating Lua objects during callback issue

Tags: api, delphi, lua

I making simple project on Delphi + Lua to use Delphi visual components through RTTI. Main implementation idea based on `luna.h`. I like Blizzard's idea of using templates stored in xml (when you can put several objects on TPanel for example and use it as template), so I almost implemented that also.

The problem is: everything works fine until I creating objects through callback from Lua made with almost same code as `luna.h` Inject code. If this object have "inherits" xml attribute callback function calls creation of objects stored in xml, creating another object through yet another injection. And I receive errors leading to lua51.dll.

Maybe that problem caused by using stack by both callback and Inject while callback function not returned result yet. So can I use stack and create objects through callback? If not - is there any workarounds to implement it? Blizzard really made it somehow.

More details:
1. Application registering Lua objects (for example `TPanel` and many others) through

```
  cn := T.ClassName;
  f := @StaticOnCreate;
  lua_pushlightuserdata(L, self); // put offset to self into lightuserdata
  lua_pushcclosure(L, f, 1);
  lua_setglobal(L, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(cn))); // T() in lua will make a new instance.
```

difference from luna.h - application also stored pointer to object (Delphi objects are pointers) to avoid generics (c templates)
2. Now Lua have `TPanel` in global table
3. By using

```
p = TPanel("somename")
```

in script, Lua calls application's StaticOnCreate.
4. StaticOnCreate extracts object and calls class's function

```
  o := TLuaClassTemplate(lua_topointer(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
  result := o.OnCreate(L);
```

5. `OnCreate` function extracts params like `name` etc and creates exact visual object of type `TPanel` and by using same code as `luna.h` for `inject` function

```
  lua_newtable(FL); // create a new table for the class object ('self')
  obj_index := lua_gettop(FL);

  lua_pushnumber(FL, 0);

  a := lua_newuserdata(FL, SizeOf(pointer)); // store a ptr to the ptr
  a^ := obj; // set the ptr to the ptr to point to the ptr... >.>
  luaL_newmetatable(FL, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(cn))); // get (or create) the classname_metatable
  lua_pushstring(FL, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode('__gc')));
  lua_pushlightuserdata(FL, self); // put offset to self into lightuserdata
  lua_pushcclosure(FL, @StaticGc_T, 1);
  lua_settable(FL, -3);
  lua_setmetatable(FL, -2); // userdata.metatable = classname_metatable

  lua_settable(FL, obj_index); // self[0] = obj;

  f := @StaticThunk;
  // register the functions
  for i := 0 to length(ClassApiArray) - 1 do begin
    lua_pushstring(FL, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(ClassApiArray[i].name)));
    lua_pushlightuserdata(FL, self); // put offset to self into lightuserdata
    lua_pushnumber(FL, i); // let the thunk know which method we mean
    lua_pushcclosure(FL, f, 2);
    lua_settable(FL, obj_index); // self["function"] = thunk("function")
  end;

  lua_pushvalue(FL, -1); // dup object on stack top
  rec.ref := luaL_ref(FL, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // store object as ref
  ...
  result := 1;
```

returns Lua object through stack, so now p from `p = TPanel("somename")` is object isntance.

But issue if I trying to implement xml templates and step 3

```
p = TPanel("somename", "xmltemplatenodename")
```

and during execution step 5 in `OnCreate` if I see there is `inherits = xmltemplatenodename`. So during step 5, before `inject`, application searching for exact `xmltemplatenodename` - if found creating more objects with `inject` for each object. And only after that continues execution of step 5 with own `inject`. Here I have errors leading to lua51.dll after creating 2-3 objects from `xmltemplatenodename`. But if application uses same xml as source and creates same `xmltemplatenodename` objects outside of `OnCreate` - there is no errors.

`Inject` for xml object slightly different, isntead of leaving object in stack it registers it by object name

```
  lua_setglobal(FL, PAnsiChar(objName8));
```

Comment: I think its hard to know what is actually going on here from your description. That said, I don't think Lua has any limitations as to what you can do in callbacks (the only limitation I know of has to do with coroutines)

Comment: `More details` added.